# Fortran reinterpret_cast Equivalent

Tags: casting, fortran

I have some functions written in Fortran that take a structure as an argument, but the caller has the data stored in an `INTEGER*4(2)` array.  In order to avoid the copy between the two data structures, I'm wondering if the following implementation of a C++-like reinterpret_cast is valid according to the specification:

```
STRUCTURE /TimeStamp/
    INTEGER*4 secondsSinceEpoch
    INTEGER*4 nanos
END STRUCTURE

STRUCTURE /reinterpret_cast/
UNION
    MAP
        INTEGER*4, POINTER :: array(:)
    END MAP
    MAP
        TYPE (TimeStamp), POINTER :: tstamp
    END MAP
END UNION
END STRUCTURE

SUBROUTINE set_time(timeArg)
    INTEGER*4, TARGET :: timeArg(2)
    RECORD /reinterpret_cast/ time
    time % array => timeArg
    time % tstamp % secondsSinceEpoch = 12
    time % tstamp % nanos = 0
END
```

Is this implementation of the `set_time` method guaranteed to work (e.g., set the values of `timeArg(1)` and `timeArg(2)`)?

Comment: Note this is not Fortran. At least not standard Fortran. It is a DEC extension. This has never been part of any Fortran standard and many compilers will not accept this extension.

Comment: Certainly not according to Fortran with those structures, union and maps.  Do you have a particular compiler in mind?

Comment: *valid according to the specification* Which specification do you have in mind? As I said, certainly not any Fortran standard. Intel Fortran manual maybe.

Comment: You can do much better and using standard resources with `c_ptr` which is interoperable with `void *`. You are responsible to make the cast valid. But it is not your question, so I am not going to go into details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, your function is not guaranteed to work by the Fortran standard and many compilers will refuse the syntax altogether. I am not sure whether Fortran pointers are allowed in the DEC `structure`s and if yes, whether you can `union` them. They (`structure` and `union` and `record`) were designed before Fortran pointers were put into the standard and are strongly discouraged for new code, but it is quite possible Intel allowed Fortran pointers in allowed them.

Much easier (at least for me) way is to use Fortran standard `type(c_ptr)` which is basically the C `void *` pointer.

```
SUBROUTINE set_time(timeArg)
    USE, INTRINSIC :: ISO_C_BINDING

    INTEGER(c_int_32), TARGET :: timeArg(2)
    type(TimeStamp), POINTER :: tstamp

    CALL c_f_pointer(c_loc(timeArg), tstamp)
    tstamp % secondsSinceEpoch = 12
    tstamp % nanos = 0
END
```

I also changed the `INTEGER*4` because it is also not standard conforming and not guaranteed to be C-interoperable.

Do note that the address of the `target` dummy argument is valid only in the subroutine unless the actual argument is pointer or target.

Comment: I just stumbled across the `EQUIVALENCE` statement while attempting to learn a limited subset of Fortran.  Too bad it can't be used with dummy arguments.  It would be much more expressive to write `EQUIVALENCE (timeArg(1), tstamp)` as opposed to using C-binding functionality to achieve this.

Comment: Equivalence is very limited and old. It was not exteded for the features that were brought by Fortran 90 so you can't use it for pointers. The syntax you are suggesting would not work even without dummy arguments.

Comment: Within the context of my previous comment, neither of the variables would need to be pointers.  Assuming *tstamp* is no longer a pointer, and *timeArg* is no longer a dummy argument, the result of the `EQUIVALENCE` statement is to make *tstamp* and *timeArg* aliases to the same 8-bytes in memory, but with different types.  My use of pointers in the original question was because that is the only way I could think of to trick Fortran into creating an alias of a different type.  I later learned that the `EQUIVALENCE` statement provides exactly that functionality.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is the F90-standard function [TRANSFER](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/TRANSFER.html). It interprets the bit representation of the operand as if it was of the same type of another variable (the "mold"). Thus, this:

```
USE ISO_FORTRAN_ENV ! For the REALnn and INTnn constants
REAL(REAL32) r
INTEGER(INT32) i
r = 1.0
i = TRANSFER(r, i) ! The second "i" here is unevaluated, just gives the type
```

Is equivalent to this:

```
float r = 1.0;
int32_t i;
i = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(&f);
```

Note that the REALnn and INTnn constants are from Fortran 2008, so your compiler might not have them. I just used them as examples to make sure that the types were compatible, since just like in C, the standard does not say precisely how big a "default real" or "default integer" are.

**As an example**, I frequently use this function when creating Fortran-based MEX functions in Matlab, since the Matlab interface with Fortran is based on F77 and does not allow you to use pointers to Matlab memory directly, unlike the C interface. I use the TRANSFER function and the ISO_C_BINDING module (F2003) to cast the "integer" (actually a C pointer) Matlab gives me to the Fortran type C_PTR, to a Fortran pointer. Like this:

```
USE ISO_C_BINDING ! For C_PTR and related functions
INTEGER(INT32), POINTER :: arrayPtr(:)
mwSize n ! This is a type defined in the Matlab-Fortran interface
mwPointer myMatlabArray = ... ! So is this
TYPE(C_PTR) cPtrToData

! Cast the returned C pointer to the data (Matlab interface returns an integer type)
cPtrToData = TRANSFER(mxGetData(myMatlabArray), cPtrToData)
! Since Fortran arrays/pointers have size information, get the length
n = mxGetNumberOfElements(myMatlabArray)
CALL C_F_PTR(cPtrToData, arrayPtr, [n]) ! Associate the Fortran ptr
array(3:7) = ... ! Do whatever, no need to copy
```

Which is the rough equivalent to the C version:

```
mxArray* myMatlabArray = ...; //
mwSize n = mxGetNumberOfElements(myMatlabArray);
int* arrayPtr = (int*)mxGetData(myMatlabArray);
array[3] = ... // Do whatever, no need to copy
```

So in both cases these MEX functions could be called with Matlab array of Matlab type int32.

Comment: As a side note, it does not have to "transfer" one object to another one; it can give you an array of `INTEGER(INT8)` from a type of a larger size. You could use this for example to implement binary serialization of derived types.

Comment: I don't think this is directly usable. It is perfectly fine for your example, but not for the OP's problem, because he needs to cast **pointers**. And Fortran pointers in `transfer` will take the *target*, not the *address*.

Comment: @JavierMartín I initially attempted to do this using TRANSFER, but got a compile-time error stating that I couldn't pass a temporary to something with an INTENT(out) (e.g., `CALL set_time(TRANSFER(...))`).  Doesn't that error imply that the bytes are actually being copied into another memory location, instead of the same memory address being treated as if it were some other type?  I'm looking for a way to do the equivalent of `uint16_t b[2]; uint32_t &a{*reinterpret_cast<uint32_t*>(&b[0])};` in C++, but in Fortran.  Note the **&** that makes *a* an alias to *b*, instead of a copy of *b*.

Comment: @JeffG Yes, transfer *does* copy the bytes, the most accurate description would be to say that `z = TRANSFER(x, y)` is equivalent to `z = *reinterpret_cast<decltype(y)*>(&x)`. Furthermore, using TRANSFER with Fortran types applies to the pointed-to, data. You'd have to go Fortran variable -> C ptr -> Fortran ptr; in that case you don't even need TRANSFER, just C_LOC and C_F_POINTER.